# what does the tag "div.img img" mean?

Tags: css, css-selectors

i understand the general idea of creating a class tag, such as .center or p.center, but what does it mean to do something like "p.center p"? i saw an example like this in creating an image gallery with css. what does the div.img img mean? thanks a bunch!

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.img
{
  margin: 2px;
}   
div.img img
{
  display: inline;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
div.img a:hover img {border: 1px solid #0000ff;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="klematis4_big.htm"><img src="klematis4_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90" /></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: They aren't tags, they are selectors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All of the answers given so far are correct, but perhaps also explaining what it isn't will help.

While `div.img img { }` will affect `img` elements contained in `<div class="img">` elements, here are some elements that it will not affect:

```html
<body>

  <img src="klematis4_small.jpg" alt="Klematis"><br>
  This image is not contained in a div, therefore it cannot possibly be
  contained in a div of the class "img" and is therefore unaffected.

  <div>
     <img src="klematis4_small.jpg" alt="Klematis"><br>
     This img element is in a div, but the div is not of the class "img",
     so the img element is unaffected.
  </div>

  <div id="img">
     <img src="klematis4_small.jpg" alt="Klematis"><br>
     This img is contained within a div that has an ID of "img", but it is
     also not of the class "img" and is therefore unaffected.
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 9):

It means

> Select any `img` element
>   that is a descendant of a `div` element with the class `img`.

The `img` class has no special meaning. It just looks a little confusing in this example.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: fixed (somewhat)

Comment: I fixed it a little more also

Comment: To be unnecessarily pedantic, a selector technically matches one element at a time (and repeats for each other element in the tree that satisfies it), hence my use of "any", but... I shan't go on :P

Answer (score 3):

The `div.img img` selector will style img tags inside divs with the class "img". For example:

```
<div class="img">
    <img src="foo.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

In short, only img tags that are contained within div tags having the class img will be styled by that selector.